# MongoDB for reporting on external database

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm starting to use MongoDB for reporting/analytics. I currently have a system that uses SQL Server to store all the information. The problem is that I don't know if I should store the user editable information in the MongoDB database.

For example, I could store info like:

```
[
    { user: {id: 123, name:"John Smith"}, login_count: 5}
    { user: {id: 564, name:"Mike Doe"}, login_count: 3}
    { user: {id: 678, name:"Mary Torres"}, login_count: 1}
]
```

So, if I want to run a report to list the "users with most logins", it's easy because I have the names there.  However, if the user name is changed, I need to update all the de-normalized data in the NoSQL database.  If I store only the ID instead, there's no problem on updating the user names, but when I want to show the report I have to query the SQL Server database too.

How would you handle this?

Comment: Is it the problem based on that a given userid has many repeating filds behind (addresses, phonenumbers and so on)? While for me seems that the name is quite dependent from the id.

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of information associated to that id that I would want to show in the report.  The question is whether I should put that information in mongo or just put the Id there and keep the information in SQL Server.

Comment: I would not mix the two db engines, i would use either mongo or SQL server, my point of view for the decision would: if the load probably will exceed the capacity of the SQL server would go with mongo. There is some best practices which with probably one able to design a datamodel in mongo which with you will not have to face with the issue that you store things sevaral times and get problems for inconsistency. It is covered in the trainings what they provide online at: https://education.mongodb.com/. If you provide your model we can make suggestions too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DBRef](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref) or Manual references:

you need storage first the user info:

```
db.user.insert({id: 123, name:"John", "lastName":"Smith"})
db.user.insert({id: 564, name:"Mike", "lastName":"Doe"})
db.user.insert({id: 678, name:"Mary", "lastName":"Torres"})
```

and in collection login only need the id from user collection

```
[
    { user: 123, login_count: 5},
    { user: 564, login_count: 3},
    { user: 678, login_count: 1}
]
```

but you need user name

```
flag=db.svlogin.find({"field.login_count":5})
user=db.user.find({"_id":flag[0]['user']})
print user[0]
...
{id: 123, name:"John", "lastName":"Smith"}
```

in this example I use Python....
remember, MongoDB is not RDBMS database...

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that it is best to store the user-editable, relatively static information in SQL server and the transactional data in MongoDB. There have been some advances with the analytics tools for Mongo so I would look to try to solve the problem of blending the user-editable data and with the ID for reporting higher up and not in the database itself.

For example, there is a company called [Knowi](https://www.knowi.com/mongodb-analytics) that allows you to blend MongoDB data and SQL Server data and create a virtual dataset for reporting and dashboards.  For your use case, you just need a common field (ID?) that is present in both your MongoDB collection and your SQL Server table so you can join the data.  I've used them before for a similar use case and the query performance is good even with the join.